# c# windows form - selecting drawn rectangles from picture box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am drawing rectangles inside a picture box, based on data that is being pulled from database. Everything works correctly, now my question is, is that possible to select created rectangles? I'd like to be able to select the rectangle and change the data in it.

I guess one of the options will be to along with rectangles display the list of them, and select them from there.

If anyone has any experience with this, I would greatly appreciate a tip.

Thank you,

H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, instead of adding directly a rectangle to the form picture box, create a custom windows forms control that holds a rectangle, and add it to the form directly, or to some kind of container.

There you can easily handle the click event of your custom control.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09w21bsz.aspx) for help on how to do this.